# Why my Java project doesn't see my jTDS database driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I'm trying to connect with SQL Server local database, I connected with it successfully from IntelliJ level, and there was information that I need to install jTDS driver to use it. I downloaded latest version of it and added as a library from my lib dir in project, despite this java says that it couldn't find the class, maybe I installed it wrong? Here is my code

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://./TPO");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Books";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlString);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error output]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `net.sourceforge.jtds` is a namespace, not a class. Have you tried `Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")` instead? Is the `jtds.jar` file in your classpath? Ref: [Why do I get a ClassNotFoundError when calling Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")?](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#classNotFound)